# Sharing data between two input fields by ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 input fileds lets say input1 and input2. I have event such that  everything  I type in input1 it shows in input2. 
Now the condition is if i manually change or type something in input2 , the event i had created above should not work.

I guess need to use count loop but I am confused.

**html code:**

```
<input placeholder="Organization Name" [(ngModel)] = "orgName" (ngModelChange)="setdomain($event)">

<input placeholder="Business + Sub Domain" [(ngModel)] = "subdomain">
```

**fragment of TypeScript file:**

```
subdomain : string;

setdomain(name) {
    this.subdomain = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g ,'');
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate deep. The condition is you manually change or type something in input2 , the event you created above will not work?????

Comment: If i manually type or change something in input2 , the event i created should not work . I mean event should be destroyed if i manually change in input2.

Comment: Why can't you use ngOnDestroy()  function in your .ts file

Comment: ya but can you help me writing code ?

Comment: It look like this ngOnDestroy() {
  this.setdomain.unsubscribe();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the simplest way is creating temporary variable, which will store unique subdomain name and create method, which will be passing to the variable appropriate value. For example:

in ***.component.ts** :

```
  defaultSubdomain: string;
  uniqueSubdomain: string;

  setdomain(name) {
    let expectedResult = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g ,'');
    this.defaultSubdomain = expectedResult;
  }

  setUniqueDomain(name) {
    this.uniqueSubdomain = expectedResult;
  }
```

and in ***.component.html** :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Organization Name" [ngModel] = "orgName" (ngModelChange)="setdomain($event)">
<input type="text" placeholder="Business + Sub Domain" [ngModel] = "uniqueSubdomain || defaultSubdomain" (ngModelChange)="setUniqueDomain($event)">
```

I created [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/550p9luq2OkY0NmrhJV1?p=preview) for you. Tell me if that's what you meant.

Comment: thanks bro , this was what i needed. 
but I want to ask something 

`setUniqueDomain(name) {
    this.uniqueSubdomain = expectedResult;
  }`

do we need that event? and can you explain little bit about '||' symbol how do it work?

Comment: || sybol mean logical OR. JavaScript treat null value as false, so "uniqueSubdomain || defaultSubdomain" mean: if uniqueSubdomain exist then uniqueSubdomain, else defaultSubdomain. Do you understand?

Comment: hello bro! I found a bug in the code!
it actually worked because setUniqueDomain() throws error in console and it is javascript error so the app stoped working due to this error and we felt it actually worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

cant you just the defaut value of input2 to that of input1. I think it should work.

```
<input placeholder="Organization Name" #input1>

<input value=input1.value placeholder="Business + Sub Domain">
```